There should be a "facial-expression", or at least a "face" tag
The face is the main, non-verbal emotional interface between humans (at least, that is my not-so-bold claim as a non-expert). How emotions are translated into expressions and why certain expressions look the same / are the same when they are responding to different, seemingly unrelated stimuli are relevant topics on a psychology and neuroscience Q&A-site, no? I am tempted to mention the the recognition of facial expressions is also a relevant topic, but that may already be included in the recognition tag, not sure because it doesn't have a description.
If facial-expression is too specific to be a tag, then face could be a tag. The hypothetical face tag could include everything about facial expressions, as well as the recognition of familiar faces (again, this may be included in the recognition tag), how certain facial features are often perceived (which varies over cultures and ethnicities obviously) and correlates between facial features and psychological / neurological traits. There's probably a host of other relevant topics that could go under a face tag.

Just noting that there is an existing tag for body-language, and I just created emotional-expression.

I searched for the search term 'face' across the site and >500 questions popped up. Not all of those hits related to a question on faces per se, but enough of them did to make it a relevant tag imo, at least in a glance. I think the face tag is a bit awkward, but I think it's good nonetheless, because it includes facial recognition, as well as facial emotions, emotion recognition etc, as you allude to in your question.
Perhaps other users can drop in answers or comments so that we can come up with a better tag name, or perhaps with multiple more specific ones. For now I like face.
To your latest question Why do people express disgust when enjoying to certain music? I have generated the face tag to meet your request.
Would you be willing to take a bash at generating the face tag description? If yes, you can click on the tag in your question and add the tag wiki. I think with the descriptions given in your question I think you could quite easily come up with a tag wiki. If your rep count doesn't allow to do this, please ping me and we can work something out.

My rep does not allow me to do so no, but I'll gladly submit a description for approval. Thanks for the help!

I have submitted one now. It's the first time I've ever made a tag so I'd love to receive any advice on how to improve it. Perhaps it should be more concise? Maybe I don't mention enough, or too much?
